# OpenLayers Plugin with on-thy-fly-transformation causes wrong coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am using the OpenLayers Plugin with the maps from Google Satellite. In Qgis I have chosen on-the-fly-transformation into WGS 84. But the WGS 84 coordinates in Qgis are now 0.15 degrees further E than they should be. When I am setting on-the-fly-transformation into UTM 32 N the values seems to be slightly wrong as well.

When I am loading the OpenLayers Plugin into Qgis do I have to confirm somewhere what the original projection is? Or what is the problem here?

Qgis 1.8.0 on Mac 10.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the QGIS Openlayers plugin, the **project** CRS **must** be EPSG:3857. Simply because the tiles Google serves come in that projection, and reprojection of single tiles looks nasty.

Other layers you load can still have other CRS, if you have enabled on-the-fly-reprojection..